# Running a program using shared libraries on Linux

Tags: linux, libraries, intel-fortran

I compiled a program using Intel Fortran compiler on a Linux machine. I can run the program on the Linux machine were Intel Fortran Compiler is installed. However, when I copied the executable to another Linux machine without Intel Fortran Compiler installed I have the following error message:

> error while loading shared libraries: libmkl_intel_lp64.so.1: cannot
> open shared object file: No such file or directory

My question is: Is it possible to execute my program without having to install Intel Fortran Compiler? Is it possible to just use the shared libraries required (I copied the missing library but I had the same error message)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Intel compiler family; it might be a) possible to statically compile your program or b) you could (might be allowed to?)  distribute the required library/-ies files with your program.

Comment: try to add the missing file (libmkl_intel_lp64.so.1)

Comment: I alrady try to add the missing file to the computer without Intel Fortran installed but I had the same error message.

Comment: How can I distribute the required libraries with the program?

Comment: Are you *exactly* following the Link Advisor?  https://software.intel.com/sites/products/mkl/mkl_link_line_advisor.htm They do have an option for static linking. How do you setup `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the target computer? Does the target library have MKL installed at all?

Answer (score 0):

Put `libmkl_intel_lp64.so.1` to `/usr/local/lib64`, and run `ldconfig`